# how to document this keyword in custom components with jsDoc?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I'm using Vuejs inline template components where we register the component in a javascript file and the template in html.

the component looks something like this:

```
Vue.component('compare-benefits', {
  data() {
     // the "this" keyword in methods should refer to this object
     return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
     }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
       // I want the "this" keyword here to reference the object return in data above 
       this.isLoading = true;
    }
  }
})
```

If you are not familiar with Vue, whats happening here is that Vue framework will bind the `this` keyword in your methods to the object you return from the data() method.

How do I use jsDoc here and tell it that the `this` keyword here is in fact referencing that object?

**EDIT**: Primary reason for using jsDoc is not to create documentation but rather to have intellisense and type checking in vscode using `@ts-check`

Comment: I assume this code is in a JS file, and you're running `tsc` for type checking. Have you tried just renaming the file extension to TS? That alone would give you Intellisense on `this` that includes the component's data props (as well as `$` props).

Comment: actually I'm not running `tsc`. I'm using vscode which does typescript checking if I include `@ts-check` comment on the top of the file.

Answer (score 5):

The `this` keyword in `Vue framework` is an object of type `Vue`. You can identify it by debugging your code within your `getData` method or any other method. Moreover, the `Vue data` are properties to `this`. I have uploaded a screenshot below for you to see it from an example of my own that I am currently working on:

[image]

As a result, your code after jsDoc usage will be like this:

```
Vue.component('compare-benefits', {
    data() {
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        /** @this Vue */
        getData() {
            this.isLoading = true;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That makes sense, however just adding `/** @this Vue */` does not provide the intellisense and type checking I'm looking for in vscode when using `@ts-check` since in this case it doesn't know that the return object from data() also belongs to Vue instance. when I hover over this keyword I still get type "any". How would you document the component itself and the returned data in this case?

Comment: @tito.300 first of all, you do not mention the _VS Code_ in your question. However, the return data of the `data() function` in the `Vue framework` should always be an object as it is mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data), so you do not need to document it. Also, what happens if you hover over the `Vue` mentioned at the very beginning?

Comment: when I hover over Vue I see `(alias) const Vue: VueConstructor<Vue>` . I Edited my question.

Comment: @tito.300 No matter what I have tried in order for the intellisense to understand that `this` is a `Vue object`, it simply does not. Probably, it is not supported at the moment or it gets confused by the fact that `this` during development is in a function, in an object, in another object and in another function. For another instance, the following `/** @this Vue */
function setName(test) { this.test = test; }` understands that `this` is a `Vue` type. On the other hand, the jsDoc documentation is clear that for `this` you need to set @this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Vue.js. However, my knowledge of JSDoc might help you.
'this' keyword can be documented as follows

```js
/**
 * @this Vue
 */
```

Here 'Vue' should be declared in JSDoc. You might be able to find it in Vue.js docs.
You may look into [this file](https://github.com/KumarSidharth/cricketAuction/blob/master/database/connect.js) for examples about creating classes, enums, functions, etc. and their usages in JSDoc.